# Android: Update a TableLayout in background

Tags: java, android

Working on an Android application, and I need a TableLayout to update on a regular basis without clogging the UI thread.  Here is the TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/pidata"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

Here is the gist of the code that needs to run, and update the `TableLayout` with new data every couple of seconds.

```
public static TableLayout piTableLayout; 
public static HashSet<PIModel> PiData; 

piTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.pidata);

while (isRunning) {
    PiData = getPiData();
    piTableLayout.removeAllViews();

    for (PIModel model : PiData) {   
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        rowParams.setMargins(0, -4, 0, -4);
        rowParams.height = 40;

        TextView pointNameText = new TextView(this);
        pointNameText.setText(model.getAttributeName());
        pointNameText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        pointNameText.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
        pointNameText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("white"));
        pointNameText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        pointNameText.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);

        TextView valueText = new TextView(this);
        valueText.setText(model.getValue());
        valueText.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
        valueText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("white"));
        valueText.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);

        piTableLayout.addView(row);
        row.addView(pointNameText);
        row.addView(valueText);
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

**Previous Code**

```
Handler piHandler = new Handler();
Runnable piRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            piHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //logic to add to TableLayout
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }   
    }           
};
new Thread(piRunnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call Thread.sleep on the UI Thread, cause it will block all updates of the screen while the method doesn't finish, you must either use one of the following solutions:

- Use android.os.Handler with repeting messages (handleMessage) that will run on UI Thread but will wait on background for new messages to arrive; (Simply solution)
- Use a Thread by yourself and post messages to a Handler to go back to UI Thread; (Best solution)
- Use a CountdownTimer (that does need an fixed ammount of time to start and reachs 0, stoping the proccess);
- Use AsyncTask with an while(true) loop and use publishProgress from doInBackground and handle the state change at onProgressUpdated to touch the UI (Not recomended, cause AsyncTasks must have short lifes);
- Use a Service to do the same as the AsyncTask and send Broadcasts to the Activity; (Complex solution)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply!  This is my first Android application, so I am not too privy on the ins and outs of threading.  My previous code was using a handler and handler.post, and it seemed to be working just fine until we had a SurfaceView that was being updated from another thread.  Did realize the thread.sleep would keep block the Surface View.

Comment: Using SurfaceView needs to post update to canvas, you sure you need such?

Comment: I couldn't post the additional code that used the handler so i edited the original.  We have to use a surface view because we are drawing circles on the UI.  We are using a drone SDK and drawing circles around certain geolocations.

So, we need a combo of a table that updates, and drawn circles that update.

Comment: You can simply override onDraw of a regular View instead of a RecyclerView if the updates are seconds apart

Comment: Why don't you use the same Runnable to update the SurfaceView?

Comment: I may try that.  I didn't write the code for the SurfaceView, but I am sure I can update it.  The circles will need to be drawn regularly as the drone moves.  The TableLayout, technically, only needs updated when the drone is still for 3 seconds.  So we were checking every three seconds (thread.sleep) to see if the drone geolocation changed.